# configure javadoc links in offline mode to link to local copy

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

**How do I create javadocs that link to files in the local filesystem  in offline mode?**

I am building javadocs for a java package and want the links of external packages (including `java.lang`) to point to a local copy.  This works by setting the [`links`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#links) property like so:

```
<configuration>
  <links>
    <link>/usr/share/doc/default-jdk-doc/api/</link>
  </links>
</configuration>
```

However, the `links` property is ignored when working offline, even when
linking to a local copy of the javadocs.  My understanding is that in such case, I should be using [`offlineLinks`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#offlineLinks) but I can't make it work.

All documentation I see for `offlineLinks` sets `url` to an external URL and `location` to a local file.  The use case seems to be creating links to external server, by using a local copy.  I have tried to set both `url` and `location` to the same value but this seems to be ignored.

```
<offlineLinks>
  <offlineLink>
    <url>/usr/share/doc/default-jdk-doc/api/</url>
    <location>/usr/share/doc/default-jdk-doc/api/</location>
  </offlineLink>
</offlineLinks>
```

I have created a minimal example as a [github gist](https://gist.github.com/carandraug/1e406a37cfaa6d01fb3535bed14b9015) which I am calling like so:

```
mvn --offline javadoc:javadoc
```

It has a single package and method that takes a `String` as argument.  I want the javadocs to create a link to a local copy of the docs but instead I keep getting `String` linked to `docs.oracle.com` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc program would handle the `-links` option properly, even if it was a local directory and there was no without internet connection.  The problem is the maven javadoc plugin which ignores the [`links`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#links) property in offline mode. The solution is to pass that option directly to the javadoc program via the [`additionalparam`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#additionalparam) property like so:

```
<configuration>
  <additionalparam>-link /usr/share/doc/default-jdk-doc/api/</additionalparam>
</configuration>
```

This has two problems:

1. It becomes too long if linking to many different packages. In theory, one should be able to pass multiple `-link` options in a single `additionalparam` parameter.
2. The `additionalparam` is deprecated. However, there is no other maven property to pass javadoc options directly so hopefully they won't actually remove it.

The [`offlineLinks`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#offlineLinks) property, which would map to the command line option [`-linkoffline`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#linkoffline) seems to really require an external URL. I am unsure if that's a requirement in the javadoc program or in the maven javadoc plugin.

Comment: `additionalparam` has been replaced by `additionalOptions`, which has a list of values as its content model rather than a single string.